# Problema con el menú contextual de Windows 11

Tags: windows, vscode, registro-windows

Recientemente compré un nuevo M.2 para mover ahí todo lo relacionado con la programación: Editores de texto, IDEs, compiladores... Más en específico, cambié la instalación de VSCode, además de eliminar IntelliJ y VLC media player.

Todo funcionaba correctamente excepto el menú contextual, el cual me sigue mostrando la opción de abrir con IntelliJ y con VLC sin estar estos instalados. Además, al pulsar la opción "Abrir con Code" me salta un error.

[Menú contextual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oydlk.png)

[Error al pulsar "Abrir con Code"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bCVm.png)

No se como eliminar las opciones que no deberían estar así como arreglar el error de VSCode. He probado con varios videos que dicen que se soluciona modificando los registros del sistema pero incluso aunque actualice la ruta del registro correspondiente (supuestamente) no se arregla.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.